# One rspec roles test fails, but almost identical tests succeeds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rolify

I just added the [Rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) gem, and am running some rspec tests.

2 tests are as follows:

```
  describe "roles" do

    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end

    it "should not approve incorrect roles" do
      @user.add_role :moderator
      @user.has_role? :admin
      should be_false
    end

    it "should approve correct roles" do
      @user.add_role :moderator
      @user.has_role? :moderator
      should be_true
    end

  end
```

The test result is:

```
  1) User roles should not approve incorrect roles
     Failure/Error: should be_false
       expected: false value
            got: #<User id: nil, email: "", encrypted_password: "", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, name: nil, position: nil, location: nil, admin: false, archived: false, public_email: false, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.37 seconds
7 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:67 # User roles should not approve incorrect roles

Randomized with seed 13074
```

factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user do
    sequence(:name)       {|n| "Example User #{n}"}
    sequence(:email)      {|n| "email#{n}@program.com" }
    position              "Regular"
    location              "Anywhere, USA"
    public_email          false
    password              "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
    confirmed_at          Time.now
  end
end
```

How is the first test is failing with a nil object, but the second is passing?

**EDIT**

Upon further inspection, any test for `should be_true` passes, and any test for `should be_false` fails, regardless of whether the added role matches the checked role.

Comment: are you sure that second is passing ?

Comment: Yup, counted them. Tried switching the order, tried doing it without FactoryGirl and just `User.create([@attr])`, and with all those it still had the one test pass and the other test fail.

Comment: I also tried, `should_not be_true` and "should be_nil", but still did the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your tests do `should be_true` what is happening is the should call is being delegated to the subject object (see [RSpec docs for implicit receiver](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-12/docs/subject/implicit-receiver)).  In this case, your subject object is a User instance that has not yet been saved to the database.  If your user_spec.rb file starts with `describe User do`, RSpec is automatically providing this default subject of User.new (see [RSpec docs for implicit subject](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-12/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject)).

What this means is that your tests are essentially doing `User.new.should be_true` and `User.new.should be_false`.  Since a User object will always evaluate to true, the `should be_true` test will always pass (although probably not for the reason you wanted it to) and the should be_false will always fail.

Based on the way your tests are written, maybe you meant something more like this:

```
describe "roles" do

  before(:each) do
    @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  end

  it "should not approve incorrect roles" do
    @user.add_role :moderator
    @user.has_role?(:admin).should be_false
  end

  it "should approve correct roles" do
    @user.add_role :moderator
    @user.has_role?(:moderator).should be_true
  end

end
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the example group is actually nested in a group declared with `describe User do`, yes?

The problem is that the last line of each example reads `should xxx`, but `should` has no receiver, so RSpec is substituting an instance of `User` for you.

What you want is:

```
describe User do
  describe "roles" do
    before(:each) do
      @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    end

    it "should not approve incorrect roles" do
      @user.add_role :moderator
      @user.has_role?(:admin).should be_false
    end

    it "should approve correct roles" do
      @user.add_role :moderator
      @user.has_role?(:moderator).should be_true
    end
  end
end
```

HTH,
David

Comment: Wow...totally missed that. Thanks!! Also, I saw an answer from you on another question somewhere, thanks for whatever that was. That being said, since you both answered the question as the same time with the same answer, how do I decide which one to select?

Comment: cbascom's answer has more detail than mine. I'd go w/ that one.